# About the equation $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B | C\cap D) =\mathbb{P}(A|C)\mathbb{P}(B|D) $

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples, conditional-probability

If $(A,C)$ and $(B,D)$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent, then it holds true that:
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B | C\cap D) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B \cap C\cap D)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B\cap D)}{\mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(D)} =\mathbb{P}(A|C)\mathbb{P}(B|D).$$
Now, I want to investigate this relation more deeply without assuming that $(A,C)$ and $(B,D)$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent.

Suppose only that $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|C\cap D)$-independent. Then:
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B | C\cap D)=\mathbb{P}(A | C\cap D)\mathbb{P}(B | C\cap D)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C\cap D)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C\cap D)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)}=(*).$$
Now, suppose also that $A\cap C$ and $D$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent and $B\cap D$ and $C$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent. Then:
$$(*)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)\mathbb{P}(D)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap D)\mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)}= \mathbb{P}(A|C)\mathbb{P}(B|D)\left(\frac{\mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(D)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)}\right)^2,$$
and so we see that what it is missing to obtain the initial equation is requiring that $C$ and $D$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent.

Now, I'm wondering if the assumed conditions alone imply that the initial equation holds, i.e. if:

1. $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|C\cap D)$-independent;
2. $A\cap C$ and $D$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent;
3. $B\cap D$ and $C$ are $\mathbb{P} $-independent;
4. $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B | C\cap D)>0$;

is it true that $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B | C\cap D) =\mathbb{P}(A|C)\mathbb{P}(B|D)?$$

I think that the answer is no, since if this is the case, the last equation implies the $\mathbb{P}$-indipendence of $C$ and $D$ also, and I suspect that this would be too much... I'm a bit lost finding a counter-example. Any help?

Comment: you insist $P(C\cap D) > 0$ I presume?

Comment: yes, I assumed that every time I conditioned to something, that something has non-null probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** Here is a "100% non-trivial" counter-example where every probability is neither $0$ nor $1$.  :)

Sorry this is kinda tedious but it is the "smallest" such example I can think of.  (If you allow some prob to be $1$ then smaller counter-examples exist.)

Uniformly draw a number from $\{1, 2, \dots, 24\}$ and define:

- $C = \{1, 2, \dots, 12\}$ and $P(C) = 12/24 = 1/2$
- $D = \{9, 10, \dots, 20\}$ and $P(D) = 12/24 = 1/2$
- $C \cap D = \{9, 10, 11, 12\}$ and $P(C\cap D) = 4/24 = 1/6 \neq P(C)P(D)$, so they are dependent.
- $A = \{1, 2, 9, 11\} = A \cap C, P(A\cap C) = 4/24 = 1/6$
- $P(A\cap C \cap D) = P(\{9, 11\}) = 2/24 = 1/12 = P(A \cap C) P(D)$, so $(A\cap C) \perp D$
- $B = \{9, 10, 19, 20\} = B \cap D, P(B \cap D) = 4/24 = 1/6$
- $P(B\cap D \cap C) = P(\{9, 10\}) = 2/24 = 1/12 = P(B\cap D) P(C)$, so $(B \cap D) \perp C$

Finally, when conditioned on $C\cap D = \{9, 10, 11, 12\}$, we have (excuse my abuse of notation):

- $P(A|C \cap D) = {\{9, 11\} \over \{9, 10, 11, 12\}} = 1/2$
- $P(B|C \cap D) = {\{9, 10\} \over \{9, 10, 11, 12\}} = 1/2$
- $P(A \cap B | C \cap D) = {\{9\} \over \{9,10,11,12\}} = 1/4$, so $A \perp B$ when conditioned on $(C \cap D)$.

Whew!

This "pictorial view" might be easier (pick one of $24$ squares uniformly randomly):

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C |A C |A CD|   D|   D|    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C |A C |ABCD| B D|   D|    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C |  C | BCD| B D|   D|    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C |  C |  CD|   D|   D|    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

BTW your big equation becomes:

$$\frac14 = \frac13 \times \frac13 \times ({\frac12 \times \frac12 \over \frac16})^2$$

P.S. if you allow some prob to be $1$, specifically $P(A|C\cap D) = P(B | C\cap D) = P(A\cap B | C \cap D) = 1$, then a smaller example is the 2nd row above, i.e.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C |A C |ABCD| B D|   D|    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

---

As the question is written, the answer is No, but the counter-example I have below is "trivial" and may not be what you have in mind:

- $A=B=\emptyset$, i.e. the empty set (the impossible event)
- $C=D$ and $P(C) = P(D) > 0$

Your big equation reduces to $0 = 0 \times ({P(C)P(D) \over P(C \cap D)})^2$ which is trivially true even if  $P(C)P(D) \neq P(C\cap D)$, i.e. even if $C, D$ are dependent.

Comment: Yep, probably i wrote it in a misleading way... the point is to find $A,B,C,D$ such that the initial equation doesn't hold despite the fact that conditions 1,2,3 hold... i'll edit accordingly your useful suggestion

Comment: You now have found exactly the kind of counter-example i was looking for! Thx, illuminating!

Comment: You're welcome!  Fun problem.  BTW I found the 6-square example first and really should have presented that first.  The 24-square example is just slicing it further so none of the prob of interest $=1$.

Comment: @antkam do you answer every question or do we just have the same interests? nice solution, +1

Comment: @mathworker21 - i "stalked" :) you a bit, i.e. read your other questions & answers. AFAICT, my interest is a narrow subset of yours (and my math ability is also a narrow subset of yours). e.g. i have no training in analysis or even the abstract theory of probability. [my actual training, and job, is in algorithms.] but within the narrow overlap, yes we do seem to have the same interests. also, our techniques are often different -- you are ~$10^5 \times$ better at algebraic gymnastics whereas i (due to lack of such skill) often have to resort to examples and graphical / intuitive arguments.

Comment: @antkam well, I've been a bit annoyed lately. I've stopped seeing the purpose of algebraic gymnastics. Like, they get the job done, but what's the point? The point of math, ideally, is to understand things and I don't see how some fields like analytic number theory achieve any actual understanding. I can't understand the proof of the prime number theorem at all -- how is someone supposed to *understand* that insane complex analysis involved? I don't know. I'm trying to make more graphical/intuitive arguments, but I think my purely mathematical hurts me in many ways, due to the lack of emphasis

Comment: @antkam on intuition. For example, I don't think I'm equipped to solve that pi66 recent question. I'll continue to try I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1.,2.,3.and 4., the equation in your question is true if and only if $C$ and $D$ are independent.

In order to get a counter-example, it's enough to build an example in which 1.,2.,3. and 4. hold and in which $C$ and $D$ are dependent.

Take a 52-cards French deck and a die. Pick a card at random and roll the die.

Calling $v$ the value on the die, which ranges from $1$ to $6$, set:

$C:=\{ v \geq 3\}$

$D:=\{ v \leq 4\}$

Both $C$ and $D$ have probability $2/3$, $C \cap D$ has probability $1/3$, so $C$ and $D$ are dependent.

Now set:

$A:=\{ v\in\{3,4\} $and the card is red$  \} \cup \{ v\in\{5,6\} $and the card is a heart$  \}$

$B:=\{ v\in\{3,4\} $and the card is a Queen or a King$  \} \cup \{ v\in\{1,2\} $and the card is a Jack$  \}$

We only have to show that the four condition 1., 2., 3., and 4. hold.

1.) $C \cap D =\{ v\in\{3,4\}\}$, and given $C \cap D$ the event $A$ concerns only the suit of the card while $B$ concerns only the value of the card, so they are independent.

2.)Since $A \subset C$, you need to show that $A$ and $D$ are independent.
\begin{align}
P(A)&=(1/3)(2/4)+(1/3)(1/4)=1/4\\
P(D)&=2/3\\
P(A \cap D)&=(1/3)(2/4)=2/12=P(A)P(D)
\end{align}

3.)Here also, since $B \subset D$, you need to show that $B$ and $C$ are independent.
\begin{align}
P(B)&=(1/3)(2/13)+(1/3)(1/13)=1/13\\
P(C)&=2/3\\
P(B \cap C)&=(1/3)(2/13)=2/13=P(B)P(C)
\end{align}

4.) Since the events $A,B,C,D$ have non-empty intersection, 4. holds.